# Get selected values from DB in select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I want dropdown auto select value from DB while loading. For example i have values like this:

```
<option value="1">Mango</option>
<option value="2">Orange</option>
```

but I want when dropdown load orange selected because in previous form I already select orange.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-plugin="select2" id="ddl_fruit" name="ddl_fruit" disabled="false" data-select2-id="2" tabindex="-1">
     <option value="">Select fruit</option>
     @if (ViewBag.fruitname!= null)
     {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.fruitname)
        {
            <option value="@item.ID">@item.fruitname</option>
        }
     }
</select>
```

I am using ADO.NET and using  not html.dropdown.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (var item in ViewBag.fruitname)
    {
          if(@item.fruitname == "Orange")
             <option value="@item.ID" selected = "selected">@item.fruitname</option>
            else
             <option value="@item.ID">@item.fruitname</option>
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i have many items in my select box. this is very complicated to check every name with if condition. kindly share easy and short solution. thanks

Comment: @PearlNetworks if it's possible then you set in *Viewbag.SelectedItem* and *ViewBag.fruitname* after when you fill in select control just check if already item exists in *Viewbag.SelectedItem* then you need to set option selected attributes

Answer (score 0):

Pass selected value in ViewBag.SelectedFruit from Controller to View.

In View:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.FruitName)
{    
  <option value="@item.Id" @(ViewBag.SelectedFruit == item.FruitName ? "selected" :"")>@item.FruitName</option>     
}
```

Comment: from backend i only get whole data and set into select list using viewbag.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use if condition or html helpers then you use Jquery to select specific item.

**Note:** if you are using **sections** please put this code in it.

```
$(function(){ $('#ddl_fruit').val('2') // for orange })
```

Comment: dont want to use jquery, its pure server side.

Comment: you can just share that line where you are setting ViewBag for list.